# In landscape, why do package downgrades sometimes not work?

Tags: apt, landscape, archive

I just installed the latest package for firefox across all my computers, and I want to go back to the previous one, why can't I do that?  I tried clicking on the 'undo' operation on the activity and it didn't work.

When I try to downdate to a specific version in the 'packages' UI in landscape, I can do it, but not to the previous version, why?

Answer (score 5):

The ubuntu repositories do not keep package versions for very long.  let's look at an example:

```
rsync:
  Installed: 3.1.1-3ubuntu0.15.10.1
  Candidate: 3.1.1-3ubuntu0.15.10.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.1.1-3ubuntu0.15.10.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.1.1-3 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
```

This shows there are two packages available.  One in the 'wily-updates',
and the main one in the 'main' wily archive.  Any intermediate update is
now missing.  Landscape would not be able to roll back to it.

Each archive just stores the latest package.  Since you targeted that
intermediate package for a downdate by clicking 'undo', the package is no longer there to
install, so Landscape correctly fails.  You should be able to downdate
to '3.1.1-3' just fine if you want (looking at my example).

If you were using a custom repository that kept all old packages
around, they could downdate to intermediate versions, for instance.